# How to free up memory of an Executor Service that has been shut down for garbage collecting?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, executorservice

I am working on at the moment on a program that uses a lot of threads.

A- My question is related to freeing up the executors once they have shut down for garbage collecting, what is the best way? I have read somewhere that I have to access the Future (Runnable or Callable) and affect it null for the garbage collector to pick it up.is that true?

B- Same question goes for threadpools?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: If you want an object to be freed, you should make sure you have a no reference to it any more.  If you need a reference to it, it can't be freed.  It is pretty rare that you should need to `null` out the reference.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no reference to the `Executor Service` anymore this should be done automatically.

Answer (score -2):

Resources of inner Thread CallAble or Runnable are enabled to GC after it compleate, except resource which they return.

If you want force to run GC. You should call:

```
System.qc();
```

Then GC will start his work in background.

Comment: gc not qc. And it is not forcing to run the GC, it is instead just giving the JVM a hint to run the GC. It is not guranteed that it will free anything.